# Global filtering - how to use global scope in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a published filter that I use for my articles. Guests can only view published articles, logged in users can view and apply filter (`?published=0/1`):

```
public function scopePublishedFilter($query)
{
    if(!Auth::check()) $query->where('published', '=', 1);
    else
    {
        $published = Input::get('published');
        if (isset($published)) $query->where('published', '=', $published);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I apply this in my `ArticlesController`:

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('articles.index', [
        'articles' => Article::with('owner')
            ->with('category')
            ->with('tags')
            ->publishedFilter()
            ->get()
    ]);
}
```

And on the article relationships:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article')->publishedFilter();
}
```

But ideally I would like to only define it in the `Article` model itself, since it's easy to forget to include this filter when implementing new features or views.

How can I make sure that all returned articles from the `Article` model are run through this filter before returned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE: Just use this: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/laravel-global-scope for global scopes in L5+

---

Better way is a bit too long to paste it and works like `SoftDeleting` thing in the core.

Read this if you want it http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

---

**Short way**: you need global scope for this. And here's how you do it in 2 steps (squashed a bit):

1 Create a class `PublishedScope` that implements `ScopeInterface`

```
class PublishedScope implements ScopeInterface {

public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $table = $builder->getModel()->getTable();
    $builder->where($table.'.published', '=', 1);
    $this->addWithDrafts($builder);
}

public function remove(Builder $builder)
{
    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $column = $builder->getModel()->getTable().'.published';
    $bindingKey = 0;
    foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where)
    {
        if ($this->isPublishedConstraint($where, $column))
        {
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
            $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            $this->removeBinding($query, $bindingKey);
        }

        // Check if where is either NULL or NOT NULL type,
        // if that's the case, don't increment the key
        // since there is no binding for these types
        if ( ! in_array($where['type'], ['Null', 'NotNull'])) $bindingKey++;
    }
}

protected function removeBinding(Builder $query, $key)
{
    $bindings = $query->getRawBindings()['where'];
    unset($bindings[$key]);
    $query->setBindings($bindings);
}

protected function addWithDrafts(Builder $builder)
{
    $builder->macro('withDrafts', function(Builder $builder)
    {
        $this->remove($builder);
        return $builder;
    });
}
```

2 Boot that class in your Eloquent model by calling `static::addGlobalScope(new AbcScope)`

```
// the model
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new PublishedScope);
}
```

If I were you I would use `published_at` column and check it for `null` instead of `= 1`, but that's up to you.

---

**edit** `remove` method updated - thanks to @Leon for pointing out unexpected behaviour, when using this scope together with `SoftDeletingTrait`. The problem is a bit deeper:

when you use this one with `SoftDeletingScope` or another one, that utilizes `NULL` or `NOT NULL` constraint **and** this scope is not the first one used (yes, order of `use` statements matters here), `remove` method will not work as expected. It will not remove any binding or not the one, that it should.

Comment: Another great answer, thank you very much. I agree on the `published_at` comment. And your website has been bookmarked :)

Comment: Have found a bug with this code when using on a model that also implements the softDelete trait.  When removing the scope (in remove()) $query->wheres will have more items in it than $query->getRawBindings()['where'] - in my case I had 3 wheres but only 2 bindings - and it unsets the wrong binding.  Hope that saves someone some time :-)

Comment: Managed to fix it by adding a counter to the foreach loop in remove() and only increment if $where['type'] != 'Null'

Comment: @Leon Thanks for this. Yes, there is a chance that this behaviour may happen - read my edit for more info.

Answer (score -1):

you can use trait and add your method or filter thing in booting method check the following
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes