# Laravel model event to restrict query

Tags: events, laravel-4, eloquent, querying

Is there a way in L4 to use model events to restrict all queries run using that model.

i.e. An event that fires before the query that allows me to modify the query.

Under certain circumstances I want to further restrict the records that are returned from all queries against a particular table/model.

e.g. A user of type customer should only see orders relating to them, so would like to restrict all `Order::get()`, `Order::first()` etc. by adding `Order::where('customerid', '=', '')`.

It would be good if it's possible to set this up on the model so I don't have to consider it each time I run a query - I can run it knowing that these basic conditions will be applied automatically where needed.

Comment: Global scope is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095541/global-filtering-in-the-model-in-laravel-4-how-to-use-global-scope-in-eloquent#26099020. Depending on your, in this example you don't need a global scope, but relations. Hard to say without real example.

Comment: That looks really good, but not quite sure how to access the user details in the scope object, e.g. if I create a new global scope called CustomerScope in CustomerScope->apply() I want to add $builder->where('customerid', '=', Auth::user()->companyid) - is there a way to pass the user into appy() rather than using Auth::user()?

Comment: Don't couple Auth and the scope. You can create a method in the trait, that returns what you need (be it config value, auth user property, or anything you like).