# Laravel Models, global filter

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I really don't want to have to override Eloquent to do this, and its robust enough that this could be possible without it.

Anyway I am working on a cloud style application that uses a table for subdomains. Every table in the database refers to this table to filter data into each subdomain (all using the same database).

So this means normally everywhere I need to call data I would need to apply `$model->where('site_id','=',CURRENT_SUBDOMAIN_ID);`

So is there anyway to add something like that in Eloquent? Still learning Laravel but have not found any information on this.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    $host = $request->getHost();
    $parts = explode('.', $host);
    $subdomain = $parts[0];

    if($subdomain!='main'){
        $site_settings = DB::table('sites')->where('subdomain',$subdomain)->first();
        if(!$site_settings){ //find out a better way to do a 404 or redirect
            return Redirect::to('http://testing.app:8000/login');
        }
        Config::set('request.site_name', $site_settings->subdomain);
        Config::set('request.site_params', json_decode($site_settings->params));
        Config::set('request.site_id', $site_settings->id);
    }
});
```

This is how I am figuring out what subdomain the client is currently in, through it I have a global for site_id, the last step is basically applying to a model.

Also every model has the following:

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\Site');
}
```

Comment: Use global scope - here's complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26099020/784588

Comment: Just recently found that, thank you. Problem was I was thinking filter when its more accurate to think scope lol.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking the wrong way when I could not find this, it is not a global filter for laravel it is a scope.

[Global filtering - how to use global scope in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095541/global-filtering-in-the-model-in-laravel-4-how-to-use-global-scope-in-eloquent?lq=1)

Just one of the things that laravel does in an innovative way that seems a little different then what you are used to. Great but mind blowing.