# Manual Soft Delete

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have inherited an old MySQL database, and I've written an eloquent model for it.

There is a column called "active" in the user table that accepts a 1 or a 0.

I'm wondering.  Is there a way of writing a query in the model so it doesn't include inactive users anytime the model is queried?  Much like a soft delete?

```
function __construct()
{
    return parent::where( 'active', '1' );
}
```

..seems to work but still includes NULL values

Comment: Use global scope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26099020/784588 , full example here: [softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-use-global-scope](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method in your model like so;

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

Then you can use `Users::active()->get();` to get the active users, this will allow you to still access the inactive user if you need to.

Or add a static method like so;

```
public static function active()
{
    return self->where('active', 1)->get();
}
```

You can use this with the following; `Users::active()`. As this is a Eloquent Collect you can also query the result collection.

For automatically refining the results of your models use Global scopes; [here in docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes). An example can be found from the following site, [here](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/).

Comment: Thanks Matt.  This works, but is there no way of a softdelete style solution where it would assume that you only want inactive?  ie User::all(); would return only active users, User::inactive()->get(); would return all?

Comment: To automatically refine results, use Global scopes, Jarek put a comment on your post. I have not personally used these.