# Laravel, Global scopes with joins

Tags: php, laravel

I need to define a global filter in order to get only the desires files in a table. The problem is that in need to filter based on an other relations cause I need to make a joins in the query.
My problem is that after define the global scope the relation has all rows of all the tables involved in the joins this make crash the code because there is ambiguous columns.

How i can only return the products table after filtering?

I based in the code in this post

http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

the laravel help
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes

and this
[Global filtering - how to use global scope in Laravel Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095541/global-filtering-in-the-model-in-laravel-4-how-to-use-global-scope-in-eloquent)

My code

```
class PublishedScope implements ScopeInterface {

public function apply(Builder $builder)
{
    $table = $builder->getModel()->getTable();

    $temp  = $builder
      ->select("products.*")
      ->join('products_categories as p_c', 'p_c.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
      ->join('categories as cat', 'p_c.category_id', '=', 'cat.id')
      ->Where(function($query){
          $query->where('cat.id', '!=', '888130');
        }
      );
    $this->addWithDrafts($builder);
}

public function remove(Builder $builder)
{
    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $column = 'cat.slug';
    $bindingKey = 0;
    foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where)
    {
        if ($this->isPublishedConstraint($where, $column))
        {
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
            $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            $this->removeBinding($query, $bindingKey);
        }

        // Check if where is either NULL or NOT NULL type,
        // if that's the case, don't increment the key
        // since there is no binding for these types
        if ( ! in_array($where['type'], ['Null', 'NotNull'])) $bindingKey++;
    }
}

protected function removeBinding(Builder $query, $key){

    $bindings = $query->getRawBindings()['where'];
    unset($bindings[$key]);
    $query->setBindings($bindings);
}

protected function addWithDrafts(Builder $builder){


    $builder->macro('withDrafts', function(Builder $builder)
    {

        $this->remove($builder);
        return $builder;
    });
  }
}
```

and in the model class

```
protected static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  static::addGlobalScope(new PublishedScope);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best solution but ,making a sub query in sql it work properly.

```
public function apply(Builder $builder){


  $table = $builder->getModel()->getTable();

    $sql = '
        SELECT "products".* 
        FROM (
            SELECT  "products".* 
            FROM    "products" INNER JOIN "products_categories" AS 
                    "p_c" ON "p_c"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN 
                    "categories" AS "cat" ON "p_c"."category_id" = "cat"."id" 
             WHERE  (
                    cat.id != 888130
                    )
        )AS products';  

    $builder
      ->select("products.*")
      ->from(DB::raw("($sql) AS products"));
  }
  $this->addWithDrafts($builder);
}
```